# ProgrammingError at / not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm a Django beginner I'm trying to access a table that is already present in the MySQL database. for that, I used - "python manage.py inspectdb" to get the model info as shown below

```
from django.db import models

class Datatable(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ssid
    
    family = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    validcopies = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    pool = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    volume = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ssid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cloneid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    savetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    clonetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    clretent = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sumflags = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    clflags = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    totalsize = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sumsize = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    level = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    vmname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    nfiles = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    backup_copy_cloneid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='backup-copy-cloneid', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    scanned_size_bytes1 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='scanned-size-bytes1', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    post_seg_bytes1 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='post-seg-bytes1', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    transferred_size_bytes1 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='transferred-size-bytes1', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    clone_copy_cloneid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='clone-copy-cloneid', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    scanned_size_bytes2 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='scanned-size-bytes2', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    post_seg_bytes2 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='post-seg-bytes2', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    transferred_size_bytes2 = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='transferred-size-bytes2', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    backup_copy_reduction_field = models.FloatField(db_column='backup-copy-reduction%', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    clone_copy_reduction_field = models.FloatField(db_column='clone-copy-reduction%', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'newtable'
```

and after running my Django server I'm getting an error like this:
[image: Django error]

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpQDU.jpg)
[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5LDZ.jpg)
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Why do you have `%` at the end of some column names?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback (as text)!

Comment: programming error at / not enough arguments for format string,
Traceback:
Error during template rendering
 <tbody>
             {% for x in data %}  #here it is showing error
                 <tr>
                      <td> {{x.family}} </td>
                    <td> {{x.location}} </td>
                     <td> {{x.ssid}} </td>
                     <td> {{x.savetime}} </td>
                 </tr>
             {% endfor %}
 </tbody>

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add the entire index html page (properly formatted), and where it is called (code). What is data? Where is it defined?